# Apache2 not working

Tags: apache2

I had installed lamp on obuntu 16.04  onthat time info.php work properly. I had created and delete a new file in html file.after some time when i try to run info.php then found the problem: 
The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
I had also try to restart apache2 the releted command but problem is same.

Comment: What do the Apache log files say?

Comment: Why don't you re-install apache...?

Comment: I try to reinstall but problems can't resolve. so plz send me related commands.  thank you